# Plague Inc. Fungus level

Tags: plague-inc

[Plague Inc.](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/plague-inc./id525818839?mt=8) is an insanely addicting iOS game, and the first 2 levels were challenging but I was able to kill all humans in a way that would make Omicron Persei 8 proud.

However, this fungus level has got my number.  I've been trying many different strategies, from infecting everyone and having no symptoms until the end to going very lethal from the start and everything in between, but I just can't kill the cure.  I usually start in India or China but I've tried starting in other places like the U.S., Spain, the U.K., and even regions in South America and Africa to no avail.

Anyone have any solid strategies or tips for how I might evolve a fungus to destroy the world before the cure hits 100%?

(On *Normal* difficulty, haven't even tried *Brutal* yet!)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The trick is to spread the disease first to all of humanity before you raise their suspicion.

This WILL be a long game, so I advise playing at the fastest speed.

The starting area is not that important, but I usually choose one of the African countries since land-based transmission is prioritized.

Concentrate on transmissions first. Which transmission type depends on which country you start on. Personally, I maximize Bird, Livestock, Air, and Water transmissions.

Mutations will come, but de-evolve them ASAP and get free points to boot.

If you're having trouble spreading in 1st world countries, invest one or two levels in the ability which makes drugs less effective.

If you are having trouble actually getting the fungus to some countries (Greenland I'm looking at you), invest a few points in the fungus special. This is random, though, and it doesn't work at times, so use it only if there are a few countries left.

Once everyone is infected, and at this point, you should have 70+ points, start putting points in the Symptoms. I personally get the Respiratory track (!) and work my way to Coma and Paralysis. Investing a few points in abilities that make researching for the cure harder is fine, but I would rather invest in symptoms that have chances of killing instead. Dead researchers = no research.

Have fun!

Comment: This strategy works for basically every level, by the way. >_>

Comment: Well I can't save 70+ points  after all humans are infected. Every person is infected but still the plague is unable to kill 1B people.
Any sugesstions

Comment: I'm partial to necrosis at that point because it means corpses remain an effective disease vector.

Answer (score 2):

First, give your plague the "Your plague is harder to cure" gene. It may seem that a "Your plague can evolve transmissions. Easier to cure." Would be a good idea, and it is, but this doesn't work on brutal mode.

Next, start in Greenland. Now, the only problem here is that not only do people want to take a cruise to it, people also don't want to leave. This can be solved with the fungus special.

In the meantime, evolve the Drug resistance 1, Genetic Hardening 1 and 2, and then leave it up to time. Devolve all mutations of symptoms.

Yay! You've saved up 60 DNA points and have infected everybody! Now kill them. The cheapest and most efficient path: Coughing > Sneezing > Immune Suppression > Total Organ Failure.

Works on not only normal, but brutal too!

Answer (score 1):

I have a strategy that can let you beat it on Mega Brutal.

The key to my strategy is to use the **Patho-stasis** ("Ability costs don't increase but easier to cure") gene because it relies on maxing its Spore ability to infect all the countries.
The Catalytic Switch ("Get bonus DNA from popping blue cure bubbles") gene is also incredibly useful late-game for all disease types.

**Do not fast forward at the beginning of the game**, otherwise you might miss some precious DNA points.

Start in India. First thing you need to do is use all 12 Spore Bursts immediately. The Patho-stasis gene is key here to keep the DNA costs of the Spore Bursts at 1. Without it, this strategy would be extremely impractical. Then, activate both Spore Eruptions, which would infect 4 new countries *each*, so activate them one at a time so you don't miss any red bubbles. Next, activate Spore Hardening, which would continuously infect new countries at a steady rate. This means you won't ever have to worry about sea- and airport closures or Greenland's stubbornness.

From there, fully evolve Air and Water transmissions to get to Extreme Bio-aerosol, which would be the only transmissions you need. Evolve Coughing, Sneezing, and Immune Suppression.

After that, just be patient and let nature take its course, evolving more deadly symptoms as necessary.