# Why is my Fungus not spreading/killing?

Tags: plague-inc

I seem to be getting a bug on certain Plague Inc fungus levels. In certain countries, my plague stalls and the numbers never change. My DNA level keeps rising, but the number of infected doesn't shift. I've had this near game end, where my disease was hyperlethal and massively infectious, and near the start, where it was unnoticed.

Is this a bug? Or is it something I can fix?

Comment: Same here, I can't beat fungus on normal difficulty. Maybe it's intentional to force you to buy full version?

Comment: btw. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86414/plague-inc-fungus-level

Comment: Which number are you referring to? The number of infected?

Comment: good point, fixed the q

Comment: Are you certain that it's not just that every person in that country has your disease? Tap the country name to check that.

Comment: 4 people out of a 45,000 person Iceland, and 2 out of a 4000 layer Greenland. At the very least, I'd expect them to die.

Comment: To get any spread worth even talking about in Iceland/Greenland, you pretty much **need** at least Cold Resistance I. Can't speak to why they're not *dying* if you have sufficient lethality, though...

Answer (score 3):

You need to go to Abilities and evolve things like Cold Resistance, Heat Resistance, and Drug Resistance. Otherwise, your disease will only progress very, very slowly.

If you start in a hot country, you pretty much need Cold Resistance for Greenland and Iceland.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen in two places:

USA / Japan:
  Solution: evolve drug immunity, on Brutal you need to go to level 2.

Greenland:
  Evolve Cold immunity, on Brutal, you need level 2.

---

However, with Fungus, I haven't seen the last ability really work well - where "spores are constantly released".  I wonder if it's related.